# How to (properly) specify a cross level effect with lme4/nlme

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I'm trying to specify properly a cross level effect with `lmer()` and `lme()` functions.

I'm working with a modified `sleepstudy` data version, where I added a level 2 variable: `score` to each participant:

```
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)
score <- gl(n = 5, k = 10, length = 180)
sleepstudy$score <- as.numeric(score)
```

My goal is to find the right `lme4::lmer()` (and a `nlme::lme()` analogue) syntax that would replicate the following formula:

Level 1:
$Reaction = \beta_0 + \beta_1(Days)+ r$

Level 2:
$ \beta_0= \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}(Score) + u_0$
$ \beta_1= \gamma_{10} + \gamma_{11}(Score) + u_1$

EDIT: i'm not sure why math equation are not rendered properly, so here goes a img of how it should look like:

[image]

For some unknown reason I'm having a hard time translating normal equations to `lme4/nlme` syntax.

*PS. I would use a read (if there is any) where regression equations are translated to syntax. So far I didn't find any.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error I found the proper solution for the given example:

```
lmer(Reaction ~ score*Days  + (Days|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
```

I can leave this Q/A as is or delete if that's considered best practice.